# Is there any tool/application which I can user to install multiple applications directly in Linux?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, scripts, automation, tools

I want to develop an application that lets users select from a list of applications they want to install. Then, I want to generate a script and, upon running it, all the selected applications should start getting installed. I want to save the user from having to go through the hassle of executing multiple commands to install multiple applications. I want to automate the process.

Want to know if there are already such tools available? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Hiding the complexity of installing software is what *software packages* do. In Ubuntu, that usually means using apt and/or snap package managers. You might see multiple commands as a hassle, but compared to the older methods experience of compiling and installing manually 30 years ago, *packages* are a simple, easy breeze. Two commands instead of a whole afternoon.

Comment: `apt install` allows to specify multiple packages at once, so yes, there is one of your possible tool already.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **tasksel**, provided by the `tasksel` package.

From `apt show tasksel`:

> Description: tool for selecting tasks for installation on Debian systems
>
> This package provides 'tasksel', a simple interface for users who
> want to configure their system to perform a specific task.

The description understates the power of this package. A 'specific task' could be a full LAMP Server. And it's possible to define your own custom tasks.

It's not perfect, but it is command-line based (you set that tag), it can be scripted, and it has a long history in Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Not really and yes. Not in the way you describe it but Ubuntu(/Gnome) Software Center does what you ask for ALL available software.

If you make something graphical listing all the software you support (like a list of groups of software and a drill down to specific applications), add a checkbox you can make 1 apt install instructions to install those all.

```
sudo apt -y install smplayer vlc
```

will install both, answering all questions asked with "yes" and you can keep adding packages to that command and as long as the dependencies do not clash (like msysql vs mariadb) it will work.

> Want to know if there are already such tools available? If so, please let me know.

[Tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) is an old tool that lets you install different kind of tasks with pre-set configurations (like Ubuntu, kUbuntu desktop, servers like sql, dns, file, mail). It is a 1 option install though. Not something where you select a bunch of packages to install.